# How to launch multiple files with file association?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

On the receiver app, It's possible to get multiple files:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnFileActivated(args);

    var files = args.Files;
}
```

But how to launch multiple files on the other side? Launcher only gets one file:

```
    Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

*It's a Windows Phone Runtime app*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for a Universal app to launch multiple files at once.

The provision in the API surface for being activated with multiple files is because Win32 apps (like file explorer) can launch Universal apps with multiple files.